# How to make Jackson's serialization inclusion properties respect JAXB "required" property?

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jaxb, jackson

I am using Jackson to support both Jackson and JAXB annotations and serialize objects to XML.

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.registerModule(new JacksonXmlModule());
xmlMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());

xmlMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
```

Alternatively, I tried to configure `AnnotationIntrospector`s with identical results.

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(
            new AnnotationIntrospectorPair(new XmlJaxbAnnotationIntrospector(), new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector()));
xmlMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
```

But, POJO's fields that are annotated with JAXB XmlEmelemt's required property, get ignored, because the flag is overridden by the JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL serialization strategy (null elements are ignored and empty tag is not added).

```
@XmlElement(name = "some-value", required = true) 
protected String someValue;
```

Is there a way to keep this strategy, but respect JAXB's required flag and to write an empty element every time there is no value for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `required` is used only while unmarshalling and the above behavior is [by specification](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/release-documentation.html#marshalling-element-default-values-and-marshalling).

Anyway, what worked for me was:

**OPTION 1**

Adding one more custom `JsonSerializer`.
For the specific required element (which is part of the constituents of another element, say `ObjectType`), I just set the value to empty string when it is `null` and write it away:

```
public void serialize(ObjectType obj, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    gen.writeStartObject();
    // write other elements
    String someValue = obj.getSomeValue();
    if (someValue == null) {
        someValue = "";
    }
    gen.writeStringField("some-value", someValue);
    gen.writeEndObject();
}
```

**OPTION 2**

It was suggested by `fasterxml` crew member after a discussion https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/issues/68#issuecomment-355055658

which was to

> sub-class `JaxbAnnotationIntrospector` , override method
>   `findPropertyInclusion()`